# "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'AndroidManifest.xml'"

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing

Actually,I wrote unit test cases in `androidTest`. But, after that when I am trying to run the app, I am getting this error.

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'AndroidManifest.xml'".
```

So,can anyone tell me the solution for this that how to fix this?

Comment: Does a clean build help?

Comment: No,it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this by adding

```
packagingOptions { 
pickFirst '**/*.xml' //you don't need to know the plugin
}
```

in android block in android/build.gradle file located in the plugin that causing the issue